# How can I make this class work based on a on specific variable (ID)?

Tags: java, oop

I am trying my hand at java development and running into a problem.

I have created 2 classes, Employee & Contract. I am trying to make the code in main method perform for specific employees. Each employee has an id, and a name. The code I have done is below.

**Employee.java**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Employee {

// Employee Data
public int employeeId;
public String employeeName;

// Array of all contracts assigned to an employee
private static ArrayList<Contract> assignedContracts = new ArrayList<>();

// Size of assigned contracts array
private int contractAllocation;

public Employee(int employeeId, String employeeName, String ContractName1, String ContractName2, String ContractName3, String ContractName4, int ContractId1, int ContractId2, int ContractId3, int ContractId4, int ContractCost1, int ContractCost2, int ContractCost3, int ContractCost4, int MaxAssignedEmployees1, int MaxAssignedEmployees2, int MaxAssignedEmployees3, int MaxAssignedEmployees4)  {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
    Main.createContracts(ContractName1, ContractName2, ContractName3, ContractName4, ContractId1, ContractId2, ContractId3, ContractId4, ContractCost1, ContractCost2, ContractCost3, ContractCost4, MaxAssignedEmployees1, MaxAssignedEmployees2, MaxAssignedEmployees3, MaxAssignedEmployees4);
    contractAllocation = assignedContracts.size();
}

// Print all assigned contracts to console (as table)
public void provideAssignedContracts() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("%10s %20s %20s %20s", "CONTRACT ID", "CONTRACT NAME", "CONTRACT COST", "MAX EMPLOYEES");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i < assignedContracts.size(); i++) {
        System.out.format("%10s %20s %20s %22s",
                assignedContracts.get(i).getContractId(), assignedContracts.get(i).getContractName(), "£" + assignedContracts.get(i).getContractCost(), assignedContracts.get(i).getmaxAssignedEmployees());
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}

// Number of assigned contracts
public int provideNumOfAssignedContracts() {
    // Count for number of contracts
    int count = 0 ;
    // Increment count for every contract
    for(int i = 0; i < assignedContracts.size(); i++) {
        count++;
    }
    // Return int for number of assigned contracts
    return count;
}

// Total cost of all assigned contracts
public int provideTotalCostOfAssignedContracts() {
    // variable to store cost in
    int sum = 0;
    // add each cost iteration to sum
    for(int i = 0; i < assignedContracts.size(); i++) {
        sum += assignedContracts.get(i).getContractCost();
    }
    // Return int for total cost
    return sum;
}

// Add a contract to the employee
public static void addContract(Contract contract) {
    assignedContracts.add(contract);
}
}
```

**Contract.java**

```
package com.company;

public class Contract {

// Contract Data
private int contractId;
private String contractName;
private int contractCost;
private int maxAssignedEmployees;

public Contract(String contractName, int contractId, int contractCost, int maxAssignedEmployees) {
    this.contractId = contractId;
    this.contractName = contractName;
    this.contractCost = contractCost;
    this.maxAssignedEmployees = maxAssignedEmployees;
}

// Return contract id
public int getContractId() {
    return contractId;
}

// Return contract name
public String getContractName() {
    return contractName;
}

// Return contract cost
public int getContractCost() {
    return contractCost;
}

// Return number of max employees for a contract
public int getmaxAssignedEmployees() {
    return maxAssignedEmployees;
}
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

// Create employee 1
private static Employee Employee1 = new Employee(1, "Bradley", "Contract 1", "Contract 2", "Contract 3", "Contract 4", 1, 2,3,4,300,1200,500,900, 5,10,5,2);

// Create employee 2
private static Employee Employee2 = new Employee(2, "Patrick", "Contract 1", "Contract 2", "Contract 3", "Contract 4", 1, 2,3,4,300,1200,500,900, 5,10,5,2);

// Create contracts
public static void createContracts(String ContractName1, String ContractName2, String ContractName3, String ContractName4, int ContractId1, int ContractId2, int ContractId3, int ContractId4, int ContractCost1, int ContractCost2, int ContractCost3, int ContractCost4, int maxAssignedEmployees1, int maxAssignedEmployees2, int maxAssignedEmployees3, int maxAssignedEmployees4) {
    Employee.addContract(new Contract(ContractName1, ContractId1, ContractCost1, maxAssignedEmployees1));
    Employee.addContract(new Contract(ContractName2, ContractId2, ContractCost2, maxAssignedEmployees2));
    Employee.addContract(new Contract(ContractName3, ContractId3, ContractCost3, maxAssignedEmployees3));
    Employee.addContract(new Contract(ContractName4, ContractId4, ContractCost4, maxAssignedEmployees4));
}

// Show assigned contracts for employee
public static void displayAssignedContracts() {
    Employee1.provideAssignedContracts();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Employee ID: " + Employee1.employeeId);
    System.out.println("Employee Name: " + Employee1.employeeName);
    System.out.println("Assigned Contracts: " + Employee1.provideNumOfAssignedContracts());
    System.out.println("Total cost of all contracts assigned: £" + Employee1.provideTotalCostOfAssignedContracts() + "\n");
    displayAssignedContracts();
}
}
```

The above outputs the following,

[image]

My expected output is for the console to only display the contracts assigned to employee 1, I feel like in one of my classes I will need to give employee-id as a parameter, but every time I try to progress with this I just cause more and more errors, I've tried a few solutions so thought i'd resort to posting a question.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

thanks in advance,

B

Update:

**Main.Java**

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

// Create employee 1
public static Employee Employee1 = new Employee(1, "Bradley", "Contract 1", "Contract 2", "Contract 3", "Contract 4", 1, 2,3,4,300,1200,500,900, 5,10,5,2);

// Create employee 2
public Employee Employee2 = new Employee(2, "Patrick", "Contract 1", "Contract 2", "Contract 3", "Contract 4", 1, 2,3,4,300,1200,500,900, 5,10,5,2);

// Create contracts
public static void createContracts(String ContractName1, String ContractName2, String ContractName3, String ContractName4, int ContractId1, int ContractId2, int ContractId3, int ContractId4, int ContractCost1, int ContractCost2, int ContractCost3, int ContractCost4, int maxAssignedEmployees1, int maxAssignedEmployees2, int maxAssignedEmployees3, int maxAssignedEmployees4) {
    Employee1.addContract(new Contract(ContractName1, ContractId1, ContractCost1, maxAssignedEmployees1));
    Employee1.addContract(new Contract(ContractName2, ContractId2, ContractCost2, maxAssignedEmployees2));
    Employee1.addContract(new Contract(ContractName3, ContractId3, ContractCost3, maxAssignedEmployees3));
    Employee1.addContract(new Contract(ContractName4, ContractId4, ContractCost4, maxAssignedEmployees4));
}

// Show assigned contracts for employee
public static void displayAssignedContracts() {
    Employee1.provideAssignedContracts();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Employee ID: " + Employee1.employeeId);
    System.out.println("Employee Name: " + Employee1.employeeName);
    System.out.println("Assigned Contracts: " + Employee1.provideNumOfAssignedContracts());
    System.out.println("Total cost of all contracts assigned: £" + Employee1.provideTotalCostOfAssignedContracts() + "\n");
    displayAssignedContracts();
}
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.company.Main.*;

public class Employee {

// Employee Data
public int employeeId;
public String employeeName;

// Array of all contracts assigned to an employee
private final ArrayList<Contract> assignedContracts = new ArrayList<>();

// Size of assigned contracts array
private int contractAllocation;

public Employee(int employeeId, String employeeName, String ContractName1, String ContractName2, String ContractName3, String ContractName4, int ContractId1, int ContractId2, int ContractId3, int ContractId4, int ContractCost1, int ContractCost2, int ContractCost3, int ContractCost4, int MaxAssignedEmployees1, int MaxAssignedEmployees2, int MaxAssignedEmployees3, int MaxAssignedEmployees4)  {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
    Main.createContracts(ContractName1, ContractName2, ContractName3, ContractName4, ContractId1, ContractId2, ContractId3, ContractId4, ContractCost1, ContractCost2, ContractCost3, ContractCost4, MaxAssignedEmployees1, MaxAssignedEmployees2, MaxAssignedEmployees3, MaxAssignedEmployees4);
    contractAllocation = assignedContracts.size();
}

// Print all assigned contracts to console (as table)
public void provideAssignedContracts() {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("%10s %20s %20s %20s", "CONTRACT ID", "CONTRACT NAME", "CONTRACT COST", "MAX EMPLOYEES");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i < assignedContracts.size(); i++) {
        System.out.format("%10s %20s %20s %22s",
                assignedContracts.get(i).getContractId(), assignedContracts.get(i).getContractName(), "£" + assignedContracts.get(i).getContractCost(), assignedContracts.get(i).getmaxAssignedEmployees());
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}

// Number of assigned contracts
public int provideNumOfAssignedContracts() {
    // Count for number of contracts
    int count = 0 ;
    // Increment count for every contract
    for(int i = 0; i < assignedContracts.size(); i++) {
        count++;
    }
    // Return int for number of assigned contracts
    return count;
}

// Total cost of all assigned contracts
public int provideTotalCostOfAssignedContracts() {
    // variable to store cost in
    int sum = 0;
    // add each cost iteration to sum
    for(int i = 0; i < assignedContracts.size(); i++) {
        sum += assignedContracts.get(i).getContractCost();
    }
    // Return int for total cost
    return sum;
}

// Add a contract to the employee
public void addContract(final Contract contract) {
    assignedContracts.add(contract);
}
}
```

No changes to **Contract.java**

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're maintaining the `Contract` list as a **static field**

```
private static ArrayList<Contract> assignedContracts = new ArrayList<>();
```

What that means is those `Contract`s will be shared among all the `Employee`s.

---

Making that list an **instance field** should be sufficient to solve this issue (notice I removed `static`)

```
private final ArrayList<Contract> assignedContracts = new ArrayList<>();
```

You obviously need to update its usages, such as

```
public void addContract(final Contract contract) {
   // Now this list is per-employee, not global!
   assignedContracts.add(contract);
}
```

and the `createContracts` method. You'll need to reference a specific instance of an `Employee`, like `employee1` or `employee2`.

---

The current code has a couple problems.

```
public static Employee Employee1 = new Employee(...)
```

What this code does is calling the constructor of `Employee`, but as you can see, the constructor call `createContracts`

```
public Employee(...)  {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
    Main.createContracts(...); 
    contractAllocation = assignedContracts.size();
}
```

Which uses the static field `Employee1`.

```
public static void createContracts(...) {
    Employee1.addContract(...) <-- Here!
```

What that means is `createContracts` is trying to access an instance which is **under construction**, thus, it will be `null`, and a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Basically, you need to get rid of `static` entirely for the `Employee` fields, and move the `createContracts` method inside `Employee` class itself.

Comment: Hello @LppEdd, I really appreciate the help, I kind of understand the logic..allowme to pick your brain for a second.. When changing the usage in addContract (as you showed above)  I'm getting an error 'non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context'. Do you understand this error? Can you explain what it means? 

Again, thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed it to non-static and it removed the error and ccreated 3 more.. I'll keep trying :)

Comment: @bbowesbo Being that I cannot change all your code, I'll let you do the boring part ;) The important thing is that the Contracts list *isn't* stored as static anymore, as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @bbowesbo let me know if you need clarifications.

Comment: Appriciated. Getting the following - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.company.Main.createContracts(Main.java:13)
 at com.company.Employee.<init>(Employee.java:22)
 at com.company.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:6)

I'm not asking for a solution, I think maybe I should go back to the drawing board (textbooks), I'm in over my head

Comment: @bbowesbo inside the Employee constructor, you're calling Main.createContracts. The error lies there. If you update the question with the current code I can give you directions.

Comment: I've updated it, is it anything to do with createContracts being static in Main.java? - again, many thanks

Comment: thank-you. Give me some time ;) I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189745/discussion-between-bbowesbo-and-lppedd).